# Unable to register XMPP user using Adium

Tags: ios, xmpp, ejabberd, adium

I'm using Adium to adding XMPP (jabber) user to my localhost. But installed and when i try to add new user to localhost it stuck in `Registering...`

How to register new user? Why it stuck on it?

Here is [image: screenshot]

Comment: What is the error message that you are getting?

Comment: Nothing it just stuck on it.

Comment: What is the host name you have given in ejabberd.yml

Comment: till now i didn't go for XCode, i'm first creating user registrarion.

Comment: Have you installed ejabberd?

Comment: Yes i reviewing this site : https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/install-osx/

Comment: Great!!! search for ejabberd.yml file and look out for `hosts` section... You should replace localhost with that name to register a user

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115810/discussion-between-dx-android-and-niranj-rajasekaran).

Comment: There's <<hosts:- "localhost">> in ejabberd.yml

Comment: Are you able to register a user using ejabberdctl command?

Comment: I'm also getting the same issue. Anyone has found a way to solve it?