# Adium - XMPP Account add stucks at Registering

Tags: ios, xmpp, ejabberd, adium

I'm trying to add an XMPP localhost account in Adium and failed to do so.
 While adding it I'm not getting any error, it just shows`Registering...`

I've found a link of a similar question here and gone through some of the discussions, but unable to get an idea of how to solve it. 
[Unable to register XMPP user using Adium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38068794/unable-to-register-xmpp-user-using-adium)

I'm using ejabberd XMPP localhost server.

Comment: inband registration is probably disabled (and should be disabled if you do not want tons of spammers to register accounts on your server).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a local server you could just enable in-band registration. That way you can register as many accounts as you want.

However, if you're going to make your server public, just use this configs:
Allow anyone to register:
register-> all: allow
Only registrations from localhost:
trusted_network-> loopback:allow
With that configuration you could build a program on your localhost that accepts or denies registration based on some criteria.